# Nuxt js How to import js file from assets?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I tried all the ways to import the JS file but still not found.
how to import js file from assets to nuxt.config.js and to all your website

nuxt.config.js

```
head: {
script: [
      {
        src: '~/assets/js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: 'js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: 'assets/js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: '~assets/js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: '@assets/js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: '@/assets/js/core.js',
      },
      {
        src: '@assets/js/core.js',
      },
]
}
```

Comment: src: '~/assets/js/core.js' is correct, what exactly is the error? Where does it appear, when?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plugins` directory to add js plugins to your Nuxt project.

Example - hello.js

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
 // Inject $hello(msg) in Vue, context and store.
 inject('hello', msg => console.log(`Hello ${msg}!`))
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
   plugins: ['~/plugins/hello.js']
}
```

component.vue

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$hello('mounted')
    // will console.log 'Hello mounted!'
  }
}
```

Example reference - https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins/